# Web API Deployment Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

I have created a brand new API with visual studio 2012 ultimate with default template. I tried to host it on our server (I installed .NET 4.5 on server) but its giving me following exception

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.RouteParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Mvc-4 beta was installed on the server earlier. I tried uninstalling it but it did not hep either and exception message persists. How can I get around this problem? Where can I download the mvc-4 RTM standalone installer to be installed on server?
thanks

Comment: Every time, I search for mvc-4 rtm, I get http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29935 which is for vs 2010 but i need binaries to be installed on server which are compatible with framework installed with vs 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I download the mvc-4 RTM standalone installer to be installed on server?

Here's the RTM download link that you could install on your server: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Those binaries are compatible with ASP.NET MVC 4 projects created with VS2012 and .NET 4.5.

Also make sure that you have uninstalled all previous Betas and RCs that you might have installed.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I don't have VS 2010 installed on server. Would it still work? As a side note, I should add that I just have been able to make things work on server by unistalling beta and bin deploying mvc assemblies.

Comment: Yes, it will work. If the installer detects that you do not have VS2010 installed, it will only deploy the MVC 4 assemblies in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I install it and it as answer. Thanks a much

Comment: When I installed .NET 4.5 on test server, it asked me to stop application running on .NET 4.0 (services). Does it also apply to website running in IIS or only console apps and services need to be stopped?